# Como fazer uma tabela verticalmente zebrada (alternar cores das colunas)?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu sei eu como fazer uma tabela horizontalmente zebrada, ou seja, cada linha com cores alternadas (o famoso cor sim e cor não).

Eu queria saber agora como eu poderia pelo css alternar as cores das colunas: a primeira coluna de uma cor e a segunda de outra, tanto 'td' como 'th'.

Tem como fazer isso no CSS?

Comment: <+><><+>                                                                                                    .
<><+><>                                                                                                      .
<+><><+> ??

Comment: Sim @edilson, cor sim, cor não, cor sim, cor não

Comment: Mas ao invés de fazer nas linhas, preciso fazer nas colunas.

Comment: na verdade eu escrevi isso no formato coluna, mas apareceu em linha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim?
Usando o seletor `nth-child`. Dessa forma, credito que não precise de grandes explicações, se for mesmo isso o que deseja:

```css
 td:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 }
 td:nth-child(even) {
 background-color:#cccccc;
 }
```

```html
 <table width="200" border="1">
   <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando.

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer usando combinações:

```css
table tr td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> [CSS ChessBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114520/pure-css-chessboard-with-div-no-classes-or-ids-is-it-possible)

Comment: Ah, dessa forma ficou parecendo um tabuleiro de xadrez, é legal, mas a pergunta tinha a intenção de fazer algo como foi feito na outra resposta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi isso que exemplifiquei nos comentários.